# Can't SFTP into AWS with Notepad++ (NppFTP)

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, notepad++, sftp, ec2-ami

I set up an EC2 instance using the Amazon AMIs (I believe based on redhat/centos) I set up my security profile to allow 22, and verified it works because I can SSH in just fine using putty and the ppk I created.

SFTP on the other hand is a no go.  When I try to SFTP in I get the following response:

> Connecting
>   [SFTP] Host key accepted
>   [SFTP] Successfully authenticated
>   **[SFTP] Error initialising sftp: Received a 115 messages instead of SSH_FXP_VERSION 
>
>   Unable to connect**
>
>   Disconnected

Of course, google has been little to no help.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8):

You will need to use the .pem version of your private key, not the .ppk when authenticating with Notepad++.

I ran into the same issue you did when using .ppk, however, when I converted the .ppk back to .pem using puttygen, I was able to authenticate with the server.

Here is more info on using puttygen to convert your key back to .pem in case no longer have that format: http://www.techyforums.com/index.php?showtopic=80

Answer (score 3):

Try setting your user userid in `Notepad++` to [ec2-user](/questions/tagged/ec2-user). If you have it set to "`root`" you will get the `115 error`. I put [ec2-user](/questions/tagged/ec2-user) in the password too so `Notepad++` doesn't pester me asking for a password. Because you are using an `auth key`, the password is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

look at `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`
you most likely have this kind of thing :

```
> no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,command="echo
> 'Please login as the user \"ubuntu\" rather than the user
> \"root\".';echo;sleep 10" ssh-rsa AAAAB3[yourkey]
```

Get rid of everything in front of `ssh-rsa` and the root stuff will work.